# SQL Query by code or codename?, Which is supposed to be more optimized?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I was checking through my reports written using SQL queries to see if I can further optimize my codes when I suddenly wondered.

"Would the system be faster if I filter by code instead of codename?"

Query #1:

```
SELECT owneridname, scheduledstart
FROM dbo.FilteredAppointment
WHERE statecode IN (1, 3)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT owneridname, scheduledstart
FROM dbo.FilteredAppointment
WHERE statecode IN ('1', '3')
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT owneridname, scheduledstart
FROM dbo.FilteredAppointment
WHERE statecodename IN ('Completed', 'Scheduled')
```

My initial thoughts:

1. The codename is often get from the StringMap table and code usually
   resides in the base table. So it should be faster if I filter the
   query by codes instead. Looking at the three queries above, I would
   think that query by string would be slower.
   *But results show otherwise. The result shows query #3 is the fastest among the 3*
2. Since it's querying against the same view, it should not show vast difference in resource usage.
   *Again I was wrong. Query #3 was more than 50% less exhausting compared to Query #1 and #3*

Results for the 3 queries in terms of "Est Subtree cost"

1. Query #1: Est Subtree cost: 0.325311
2. Query #2: Est Subtree cost: 0.325311
3. Query #3: Est Subtree cost: 0.190786

Anyone can explain why does it behave in this manner?

Comment: exactly how this test has been performed?

Comment: Just a small test. I guess it could be inaccurate. I used the execution plan to get the Est. Subtree cost. What should be the appropriate test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when it comes to performance comparisons, I always refer to Eric Lippert's Excellent [Which is Faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) blog.

I believe you're viewing your test results incorrectly.  Since you're not actually doing tests but estimates, the cost shown is a percentage of the query as a whole.  It can not be directly compared to the percentage costs from another estimate.

For example, let's say units of the cost are a percentage of the CPU required.  Let's also assume that since they are less complicated Query #1 & Query #2 only require 100 CPU cycles, but Query 3 requires 1000 CPU Cycles.  If we apply the math of the percentages to this is the result:

1. Query 1: 33 Cycles
2. Query 2: 33 Cycles
3. Query 3: 190 Cycles

Even though Query 3 is a smaller percentage, it takes more actual resources.

I'm also going to guess that the performance difference is entirely negligible, and therefore you should be looking at other issues like readability / maintainability.

`WHERE statecodename IN ('Completed', 'Scheduled')` is definitely more readable, but much less maintainable (What if someone changes the text values to 'Complete' and 'Schedule'?.  Therefore I would suggest this instead:

```
WHERE statecodename IN (1, 3) -- ('Completed', 'Scheduled')
```

And stop preemptively worrying about performance.

> "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." - Donald Knuth